# Getting page number on top of two-lined header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

**Objective:**
I need to get the page number of the left even pages (LE) on the left top corner: this fails when the header contains multiple lines (it is then printed on the second line).

When I add `\parbox[t]` after `\thepage`, the pagenumber is on the top left (and first line). However, I receive new errors AND when the header is only one line, it moves the text one line down. The output can be viewed here:
https://ibb.co/ZX280PM

The error:

> Argument of @iiiparbox has an extra }.

I'm using an online script (freely available) *(note this is where I added \parbox[t])*. This is a part of it:

```
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
\fancyhf{}
%% Page numbers on the top left and top right.
\fancyhead[LE]{\cropmarks\lthumb\titlefont\thepage{\parbox[t]}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\cropmarks\rthumb\titlefont\thepage}
%% Chapter name on the left (even) page.
\fancyhead[RE]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
%% Section name on the right (odd) page.
\fancyhead[LO]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
}
```

My dissertation.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dissertation}[2013/07/08 v1.0 TU Delft dissertation class]

\newif\if@nativefonts
\DeclareOption{nativefonts}{\@nativefontstrue}
\newif\if@print
\DeclareOption{print}{\@printtrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[10pt]{book}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
%% English is the default language, but Dutch is used for some sections.
\RequirePackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[nooneline,footnotesize]{caption}
\RequirePackage{chapterbib}
\RequirePackage{etaremune}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[flushmargin,hang]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
    \RequirePackage[xetex]{geometry}
    \RequirePackage[xetex]{graphicx}
    \RequirePackage[xetex]{hyperref}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \RequirePackage{xltxtra}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\else
    \ifpdf
        \RequirePackage[pdftex]{geometry}
        \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
        \RequirePackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
    \else
        \RequirePackage[dvips]{geometry}
        \RequirePackage[dvips]{graphicx}
        \RequirePackage[hypertex]{hyperref}
    \fi
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{metalogo}
\RequirePackage[sectionbib,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\RequirePackage{adjustbox}
\RequirePackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{float}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
%% If the document is not compiled with XeLaTeX, we need to use the native
%% fonts.
\ifxetex\else
    \@nativefontstrue
\fi

\if@nativefonts
    %% The native font is Utopia Regular with Fourier math. We use Latin Modern
    %% as a fallback, since Utopia lacks support for sans-serif and monospace.
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage{lmodern}
    \RequirePackage{fourier}
    %% The style for titles is small caps.
    \def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
    \def\titleshape{\scshape}
    \def\titlestyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
    \if@print
        \def\headerstyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
    \else
        \def\headerstyle{\titlefont\titleshape}
    \fi


\definecolor{wesandersonred}{cmyk}{0.00,0.90,0.86,0.29}

%% Set the paper size to 17 by 24 cm, approximately halfway between A4 and A5.
\if@print
    %% In print mode we add a 3 mm bleed on the outside of the page.
    \geometry{
        papersize = {173mm,246mm},
        layoutsize = {167mm,240mm},
        layoutoffset = {3mm,3mm},
        bindingoffset = -3mm
    }
\else
    \geometry{papersize={170mm,240mm}}
\fi
%% We decrease the margins slightly from the default (scale = 0.7).
\geometry{hscale=0.75,vscale=0.8}

%% Redefine the title command to accept an optional subtitle.
\renewcommand*\title[2][]{%
    \def\@subtitle{#1}%
    \def\@title{#2}%
    %% Add the title to the PDF meta data.
    \hypersetup{pdftitle=#2}%
}


%% Fancy style for the main matter.
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    %% Page numbers on the top left and top right.
    \fancyhead[LE]{\titlefont\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\titlefont\thepage}
    %% Chapter name on the left (even) page.
    \fancyhead[RE]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    %% Section name on the right (odd) page.
    \fancyhead[LO]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
}

%% The mainmatter style is default for normal pages.
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

%% Print the current chapter and section at the top of the page in cyan.
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\color{title}#1}{}}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \color{title}#1}}

%% Change the headrule command (from fancyhdr.sty) to draw the line below the
%% header in the title color.
\renewcommand*\headrule{%
    \if@fancyplain%
        \let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth%
    \fi%
    {\color{title}\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}%
    \vskip-\headrulewidth%
}
```

My dissertation.tex:

```
\documentclass{dissertation}
\begin{document}

\title[Test]{test}
\author{Author}{Name}

\mainmatter

\include{chapter-4}
\include{chapter-5}

\end{document}
```

chapter-4.tex:

```
\chapter[This header needs to be long to be a two line header header \\ header header header]{This header needs to be long to be a two line header}
\label{chapter_4}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
```

chapter-5.tex:

```
\chapter[This header needs to be short to be a single line header ]{This header needs to be short}
\label{chapter_5}
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
```

Could anyone help me with this task?

EDIT: added .cls and .tex examples

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please edit your question to include a minimal working example? That is, we should see the bare minimum amount of code to compile a document with your problem. Right now, for example, we can't see what document class you're using, so we can't compile your code.

Comment: @gz839918 Thank you very much! I just updated the startpost, in which I deleted most abundant code. Maybe there is still too much code in the .cls file though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dissertation.cls`, replace the page style you showed with the following:

```tex
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE]{%
    \titlefont{\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{%
      \raggedleft\thepage\hfill\titleshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
    }%
  }
  \fancyhead[RO]{\titlefont\thepage}
  \fancyhead[RE]{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
}
```

This will ensure your page number is always at the top leftmost corner, sharing the same baseline as your running chapter header (dashed blue line for comparison):

[image: A screenshot of the page header with the page number, two, sharing the same baseline as the first line of the running chapter head. A dashed blue line is beneath the digit two and the first line of the running chapter head, and the dashed blue line just barely touches the baseline of each.]

**How it works:**
In this new code, instead of having a header left side and header right side for even pages, I simply empty the header right side. On the left side, I construct a box exactly the same width of the header, and I flush everything to the right (`\raggedleft`). On the first line, I insert the page number (`\thepage`), a horizontal space (`\hfill`), and the running chapter head (`\leftmark`). This creates the appearance of a distinct "left side" and "right side," and ensures the page number and first line of the running head are always on the same line.

Comment: Thank you very much. This script works. I also included the \cropmarks and \lthumb I initially used and it works without problem. Greatly appreciated!